# Https Connection Refused on WordPress instance on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, https, connection-refused

I have setup a wordpress website on Google cloud platform. The problem is that it returns error connection refused on https.

Initially the website was using numerical IP address. Then I forwarded my domain to the VM instance IP address using the CloudFlare DNS (I use cloudflare DNS hosting as my domain provider doesn't provide Dns hosting). Changed the WordPress URL in settings to http. The domain now points to GCP VM instance.

I have enabled SSL in Cloudflare. I have enabled always use https in Cloudflare. I have checked that the firewall in VM instance allows HTTPS traffic. I have added the domain to Google cloud as well and verified it. I have manually uploaded the SSL certificate from CloudFlare to Google Cloud and applied it to work with my domain. I have installed CloudFlare Flexible SSL plugin into my Wordpress Woocommerce website.

But none of that helps.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Whats the domain you are trying ?

Comment: www.silverjewellery.pk

Comment: Right now it's returning 404 error after I enabled Google cloud provided SSL certificate and pointed it to the DNS records provides by GCP in the Cloud Flare settings.

Answer (score 1):

Upon inspecting your domain it seems like you need to do following steps :

1. Please verify this ip 35.185.255.190 is https fe lb ip
2. Cname record is not pointing towards A record so to do that [create cloud dns](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart) zone and add entries
3. Your domian nameservers is not pointing towards Google nameservers , to do that check the entries from cloud dns ns and add it by replacing your domain ns entries
4. After performing all above steps , verify by [dig](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#CNAME/) command
5. If using Google managed ssl cert in LB then make sure its been added properly and not in provisioning state
6. Follow this [YouTube  video](https://youtu.be/sTDVsMUegL8) as reference

Comment: With all the playing that I did with my deployment it became inaccessible at all. So I have deleted the previous deployment and instance and creates everything afresh. Now my server static IP is 146.148.61.174 and domain is silverjewellery.pk. i have used CloudFlare DNS to point the domain to that IP address. When I deployed I allowed HTTP and HTTPS connections and it also shows that on my deployment of Wordpress. Now I can access my wordpress deployment through silverjewellery.pk on http.

Comment: But on https it refuses connection. I have enabled SSL/TLS configuration (Full) on Cloudflare also enabled always use HTTPS. But https requests on my domain returns connection refused errors.

Comment: Also I would like to use CloudFlare hosted DNS and not google hosted DNS. So I don't think I need to create a zone and point my nameservers to Google NS as they are already pointed to CloudFlare DNS.

Comment: On adding ssl to http LB means the website will show you secure at the front end but when you are adding ssl to your cloudflare domain means adding cert at your backend , which means you also need your backend hitting https LB

Comment: If you are not using http LB then you need to redirects your traffic by editing .htaccess

Comment: I'm sorry what is LB?

Comment: Okay Load balancer got it. How do I have backend also hitting https LB?